# Listening to nodejs events in netlify deployment

Tags: node.js, events, event-handling, netlify

I want to listen to certain nodejs events. A few examples:

1. listen to new messages in my telegram account. ("telegram" library)

`client.addEventHandler(onMessage, new NewMessage({.....`

2. listen to changes in my database. ("mongodb" library)

`changeStream.on("change", next => {....`

3.listen to changes and events in the blockchain.("web3" library)

`web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {.....`

The questions and resources i found are assuming that said event is coming in as a http request over the https://my-app-3542532.netlify.app endpoint, and using lambda syntax to handle the request. But the type of request i want to handle should come from within the code, not from some kind of http request to my app.

My code console logs on local host when my telegram account receives a new message event, but it doesn't console log in the netlify terminal in the deployment.

Anybody got some resources i could read into? The netlify documentation seems to only really explain http lambda events but not code internal .on() .subscribe() or .onMessage() events.

Do i still need a netlify.toml file for these kind of events?
Does it need some special type of configuration in my deployment?